# not in a date range

Tags: sql, date, range, informix

I have an order database. Each order can have multiple SKUs on the order. Likewise, SKUs can be attached to multiple orders. Each order has a date field that stores the date it was created.

- Table1 = Details table which stores all the SKU information attached to order
- Table2 = Summary that lists Order ID and ship date which cross reference with Table1 to get more detail of each order

What I am trying to find is SKUs that aren't attached to any orders after a certain date. In other words, I want a list of SKUs that haven't been ordered in the last 30 days.

It seems that NOT BETWEEN should work, but it keeps returning SKUs that have been on orders past 7/21/2012. Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.sku, table2.ship_date
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.orderID = table2.orderID
AND table2.ship_date NOT BETWEEN  DATE ('2012-07-21') and DATE('2012-08-23')
ORDER BY table1.ship_date ASC;
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `not in` and base it on the sku table:

```
SELECT sku
FROM sku_table -- the table with the complete list of skus
where sku not in (
    -- all skus that were ordered after 2012-07-21
    SELECT sku
    from table1
    WHERE order_date > DATE('2012-07-21')
    union -- fyi union removes duplicates
    -- all skus that were shipped after 2012-07-21
    SELECT table1.sku
    from table2
    join table1 on table1.orderID = table2.orderID
    WHERE table2.ship_date > DATE('2012-07-21')
)
```

This query will also return SKUs that have never been ordered.

Comment: With the tables given in the question, this is the best you can do.  However, the query gives the list of SKUs that have ever been ordered that have not been ordered in the last 30 days; there might be other SKUs that have never been ordered which were (by definition) not ordered in the last 30 days, but they only appear in the table defining the SKUs that are available to be ordered, which is neither Table1 nor Table2.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah - I didn't read the question closely enough. I thought `table1` was the list of SKUs. I've edited the answer accordingly